# $rootScope:infdig Error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am making an app using AngularJS.

Suddenly I got this  error.

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

See my code:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="invApp" ng-controller="InvoiceController as ctrl">
<span ng-repeat="code in ctrl.codes">{{ getProduct(code) }}</span>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("invApp", []);
app.controller("InvoiceController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.codes = ["KKS", "KKB", "SNS"];
    $scope.getProduct = function (code) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../api?action=getproduct&code='+code
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            var something = response.data;
        });
        return something;
    };
});
```

Comment: What is code and why are you returning data2

Answer (score 1):

This

```
 <body ng-app="invApp" ng-controller="InvoiceController">
 {{ getProduct("KKS") }}
 </body>
```

Will create infinitive number of request. In order to help you, I need to know what you are trying to do?

EDIT:
You should execute call from controller, not from html (remove it from html). Add this line in controller $scope.getProduct('KKS');

Comment: I want to print something got from AJAX request.

Comment: Then you should execute call from controller, not from html (remove it from html).
Add this line in controller $scope.getProduct('KKS');

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function within {{function()}} you need to be careful. Interpolation runs every digest cycle and you are calling a function within that, The problem is that you are making an $http call which again triggers a digest cycle. Try calling it directly from the controller. You should make one http call when your page load and use this data.

```
<body ng-app="invApp" ng-controller="InvoiceController as ctrl">
    <span ng-repeat="p in products">{{ p }}</span>
</body>

app.controller("InvoiceController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getProducts("all your codes");
    $scope.getProducts = function (codes) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../api?action=getproducts'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.products = response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

Make your server return an array containing all your products(getProducts instead of getProduct) at once and then iterate over it using ng-repeat.
It should look like something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and
>   each $digest cycle triggers a state change and subsequent $digest
>   cycle. AngularJS detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop
>   from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

It is a bad practice to render your data via a server call. Because the angularjs life cycle would call the server each time.

Here is how I would implement it:

```
 var app = angular.module("invApp", []);
 app.controller("InvoiceController", function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.getProduct = function (code) {
         $http({
             method: 'GET',
             url: '../api?action=getproduct&code='+code
         }).then(function successCallback(response) {
             $scope.product = response.data;
         });
    }; 
});

$scope.getProduct('KKS');
```

Inside your template use the product that was saved in the scope.

```
<body ng-app="invApp" ng-controller="InvoiceController">
 {{ product }}
</body>
```

Comment: Can you solve it now @HannounYassir ? I edited my question.

Comment: My answer is still valid. You should loop through your array of codes and then save them to the scope, then render them on your template.

Answer (score 0):

You have few problems in your code.

The return of `something` is wrong; you are trying to *return* from a method doing an async call.

What you should instead do is to add in the `$scope` the fetched data as soon as it gets loaded, therefore:

```
$scope.codes = ['KKS', 'KKB', 'SNS'];

$scope.getProduct = function (code) {
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '../api?action=getproduct&code=' + code,
  });
};

$q
  .all($scope.codes.map(function (code) {
    return $scope.getProduct(code);
  }))
  .then(function (products) {
    $scope.products = products;
  });
```

and then:

```
<body ng-app="invApp" ng-controller="InvoiceController as ctrl">
  <span ng-repeat="product in ctrl.products">{{ product }}</span>
</body>
```

Comment: No. Because I have not only "KKS". I have 3 strings in codes array. Please review my code. I edited my question 29 minutes ago.

Comment: You keep changing your question. 

Comment: @TarequeMdHanif does it help ?